# problema con formulario vueJS y laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy tratando de crear un componente que contenga un formulario y este que sea llenado desde la base de datos con un controlador de laravel. Pero cuando genero el formulario, me aparece en consola lo siguiente:

```
    [Vue warn]: Property or method "direccion" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in
```

He mirado el formulariopor si faltaba el v-model, pero si está. Este error me aparece para todos los inputs del formulario.

A parte, como puedo hacer mención a los placeholder de laravel en vue¿? es decir si tengo esto en laravel

```
{{$usuario->id}}
```

como lo pongo en el componente de vue para que se llene mi formulario con los datos del usuario, para posteriormente editarlos.

Gracias de antemano. adjunto mi código actual.

**vueJS**
*Este es el componente*

```
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" v-model="token">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="email">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" v-model="nombreUsuario" class="form-control" >
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                    <textarea v-model="direccion" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="3">
                        
                    </textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" v-model="id">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- EMPEZAMOS LA FUNCIONALIDAD CON VUE DE ESTA MANERA LE DAMOS FUNCIONALIDAD AL BOTON-->
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
        </form>

</template>

<script>
    export default{
        mounted(){
            console.log('component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('usuarios-component', require('./components/usuariosComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('formularioactualizacion', require('./components/datosUsuarios.vue').default);


// inicio de VUE

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#contenedorVue',
    //components: {usuario},
    data:{
            id: '',
            nombreUsuario: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            direccion: '',
            token: '',
            arrayTasks:[],
        },
        methods: {
            enviar(){
                let url = '/actualizarDatos';
                axios.post(url, {
                    id: this.id,
                    nombreUsuario: this.nombreUsuario,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    direccion: this.direccion,
                    _token: this.token,
                }).then(function(response){
                    this.arrayTasks = response.data;
                    console.log("aquí"+response);
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

**homeController** desde el cual obtengo los datos que envío a la vista, en ella si puedo acceder a los datos

```
public function datosPersonales($cod_usuario){
    $usuario = \Auth::user();
    
return view('datosPersonales')->with("usuario", $usuario);
}
```

Comment: `direccion` y las demás propiedades de data que vas a usar como v-model de los inputs van en el mismo componente donde tienes el template con lo inputs.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ garacias por tu respuesta, eso estoy haciendo no¿?? en el mismo componente tengo los v-model, no¿??? es que este form, quiero crearlo dinámicamente

Comment: Por lo que veo, estás declarando la propiedad `data` cuando creas la instancia de Vue. A lo que iba es a que ese data va en el componente donde tienes el template con los inputs, que supongo que es `formularioactualizacion`, fíjate que en ese componente sólo tienes un método `mounted()` pero no `data()`

Comment: perdona @porloscerrosΨ pero soy totalmente nuevo en vue y me pierdo muchísimo... No entiendo para nada como debo de enviar los valores del controlador al componente de vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto colocalo en el header de tu archivo blade que estes usando

```
<script>
    window.data = {
      datos: {
        "id":                  "{{$usuario->name}}",
        "nombreUsuario":       "{{$usuario->apellido}}",
        "email":               "{{$usuario->email}}"
      }

    }
</script>
```

y en en tu archivo vue

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#contenedorVue',
//components: {usuario},
data:{
        id: data.datos.id,
        nombreUsuario: data.datos.nombreUsuario,
        email: data.datos.email,
        password: '',
        direccion: '',
        token: '',
        arrayTasks:[],
    },
```

y asi vas llenando dependiendo de los datos que quieres modificar.

Comment: Checa bien, el OP usa single file components y no como propones